# Django url with params, don't know how to test

Tags: django, testing

can anyone give help me how to test the following url in django?

```
path('<int:id>/update/', MyUpdateView.as_view(), name='my-update')
```

So far I have this, but it does not contains the param, therefore it fails.

```
def test_url(self):
         url = reverse('my-update')
         self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.view_class,
```

MyUpdateView)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a value for the parameter, so for example:

```
def test_url(self):
    url = reverse('my-update', kwargs={'id': 1})
    self.assertEquals(MyUpdateView, resolve(url).func.view_class)
```